# New to action script

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, class, air

I'm trying to create a simple form that adds a user new User(). But when I build it I get two errors on the same line.

> Call the possibly undefined method User. and Type was not found or was
>   not a compile time constant.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="1116" height="633" initialize="windowedapplication1_initializeHandler(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import me.*;
            var usercollection:Array = new Array();
            var userOne:User = new User;


            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {   
                userOne.fname = firstNameInput.text;
                userOne.lname = lastNameInput.text;
                userOne.dob = dateChooser.selectedDate;
                usercollection.push(); 
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:DataGrid x="832" y="9">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="First Name" dataField="fname"/>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="LastName" dataField="lname"/>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
    <mx:Form x="115" y="61" width="562" height="325">
        <mx:FormItem label="First Name">
            <s:TextInput id="firstNameInput"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
        <mx:FormItem label="Last Name">
            <s:TextInput id="lastNameInput"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
        <mx:FormItem label="Date Of Birth">
            <mx:DateChooser id="dateChooser"/>
        </mx:FormItem>
        <s:Button label="Submit" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </mx:Form>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Entities package

```
package me.entities
{
    public class Person
    {
        public var fname:String;

        public var lname:String;

        public var dob:Date;
    }

    public class User extends Person
    {
        public var crypted_password:String;

        public var salt:String;

        public var created_at:Date;

        public var last_login:Date;

        public var last_ip:String;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have two public class definitions in the same .as file and note that the file must have the same name as the public class inside.

In your case you'll have 2 files, one named Person.as and the Other named User.as. You'll have to

Person.as

```
package me.entities
{
    public class Person
    {
        public var fname:String;

        public var lname:String;

        public var dob:Date;
    }
}
```

User.as

```
package me.entities
{
    public class User extends Person
    {
        public var crypted_password:String;

        public var salt:String;

        public var created_at:Date;

        public var last_login:Date;

        public var last_ip:String;

    }
}
```

Comment: It now gives me these errors.  -Person
-1017: The definition of base class Person was not found.
-15 changed lines

Comment: Uhmm, this works for me so I don't know why it's not for you. Just tested it in a brand new project. I edited my post because the import line was not required, but it should work anyway with it. It was just useless.

Comment: @atbyrd that error is because you did not imort the Person class into the User class "import me.entities.User;"